# Using Makefile in C with more than one file

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, makefile, include

I have 6 files:

```
guiGame.c, which include guiGame.h
guiGame.h, include minimax.h,listutils.h
minimax.c, include minimax.h
minimax.h, include listutils.h 
listutils.c, include listutils.h
```

I built it in Visual Studio and I need to run it on Linux.
I tried to search how to build makefile for them but I didn't succeed to build something that works; there's something with the including that never works for me.

Can someone tell me what I need to write in every `X:<files>` line?

Thanks.

Comment: you can refer to [this](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/).

Answer (score 0):

The basics:

```
SRCS = guiGame.c minimax.c listutils.c
HDRS = guiGame.h minimax.h listutils.h

PROG = guiGame
OBJS = ${SRCS:.c=.o}

DEBRIS = a.out core *~
RM_F   = rm -f

all: ${PROG}

${PROG}: ${OBJS}
    ${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${OBJS} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}

clean:
    ${RM_F} ${OBJS} ${PROG} ${DEBRIS}
```

The residual issue is getting the dependencies correct.  The object files depend on the headers they include.  The pessimistic but simple version is:

```
${OBJS}: ${HDRS}
```

It works, but it means that if you change `guiGame.h`, `listutils.o` will be recompiled when it otherwise need not be.

There are various tools that automate the handling of dependencies.  `mkdep` and `mkdepend` are two; you can also investigate the options to `gcc`.

Note that the command lines (starting `${CC}` and `${RM_F}`) are indented by tabs, not spaces.  This is crucial.

The variable `LDFLAGS` is for specifying library locations (primarily).  The variable `LDLIBS` allows you to specify the libraries.  Object files go before libraries on the command line; the library flags can be placed anywhere.

I normally build `CFLAGS` from various parts:

```
WFLAG1 = -Wall
WFLAG2 = -Wextra
WFLAG3 = -Wmissing-prototypes
WFLAG4 = -Wstrict-prototypes
WFLAG5 = -Wold-style-definition
WFLAG6 = -Werror
WFLAGS = ${WFLAG1} ${WFLAG2} ${WFLAG3} ${WFLAG4} ${WFLAG5} ${WFLAG6}
SFLAGS = -std=c11
GFLAGS = -g
OFLAGS = -O3
UFLAGS = # Set on command line
IFLAG1 = -I${HOME}/inc
IFLAGS = ${IFLAG1}

CFLAGS  = ${OFLAGS} ${GFLAGS} ${IFLAGS} ${SFLAGS} ${WFLAGS} ${UFLAGS}
```

This allows me to adjust any option on the `make` command line.  Most people aren't so fussy (careful?).  Note that `GFLAGS` is historically used for flags to the SCCS `get` command — you might screw something up by recycling it, but you probably won't.